# Ember 2, which differences in this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, functional-programming, ember-data

I'm using this code to simulate a server delay for my gets.

```
let promises = [];
child.get('authors').forEach(author => author.get('books').forEach(book => {
  var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let time = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) * 1000;
    Ember.run.later(() => {
      favoriteList.pushObject(book);
      resolve();
    }, time);
    if (somethingWrong) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
  promises.push(promise)
}));

RSVP.all(promises).then(function () {
  console.log('Yoo! Finally!')
}).catch(function (error) {});
```

**I'm wondering (except for the `Ember.run.later()` which I use to simulate a server delay for all my "gets") if there are differences in this code below?**

```
child.get('authors').forEach(author => author.get('books').forEach(book => {
  favoriteList.pushObject(book);
}));

console.log('Yoo! Finally!')
```

And what differences with this code?

```
child.get('authors').forEach(author => author.get('books')
  .reduce((accumulator, book) => {
    favoriteList.pushObject(book);
  })
);
console.log('Yoo! Finally!')
```

I'm wondering also performances differences and server delay handle ones...

Answer (score 0):

This is a link that shows a benchmark test around different functions that iterates over one array: https://jsperf.com/array-reduce-vs-foreach/9

This shows that forEach is slower than the reduce for a sum operation.

Apart from that, you are not using reduce appropriately. You can see you are not using the previous result in your current operation. So why use reduce? You are confusing the programmer because it is expected to use the previous result and return the result in reduce operations.

(I guess that's what happenedd to you? You got this code from someone else and got confused. Right? So, use the functions for what they were designed for)